# Вопрос по list.append()

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dict, append

У меня есть небольшой код:

```
from collections import defaultdict
basket = defaultdict(lambda: [])
basket = {670142777:[{'id': 2, 'cou':6},{'id': 1, 'cou':2}]}
item = dict.fromkeys('id','cou')


item['id'] = 3
item['cou'] = 12

basket[670142777].append(item)

print(basket)
```

На выводе получаю это:

```
{670142777: [{'id': 2, 'cou': 6}, {'id': 1, 'cou': 2}, {'i': 'cou', 'd': 'cou', 'id': 3, 'cou': 12}]}
```

Почему оно разделяет словарь на непонятные ключи і и d? и как это исправить?

Comment: Потому что во fromkeys нужно передавать список ключей: `dict.fromkeys(['id','cou'])`

Comment: Но зачем вам fromkeys? Вы вместо него можете написать `item = {}` и тоже будет работать

Comment: Да, это у вас dict.fromkeys добавил в items такую штуку

Comment: Кст, проще не `defaultdict(lambda: [])`, а `defaultdict(list)`